# Date field repeat in same day but different time

Tags: 7, datetime

I have an Events Content Type with [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) Field. How can I repeat the date in different time? For sample, I want to show the event for "Sep 9, 10am-11am" and "Sep 9, 1pm-2pm". I see there is a repeat option for Date, but not the time. I also found # 4 in this [Article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1411342) has mentioned "runs more than one time per day" option, but I don't see this in Date field.