# Same day with time range

Tags: 8, datetime

I'm trying to make an events calendar that has events on a day, (e.g. Feb 2), with a start and end time, (1pm - 3pm).

However, the current date module in Drupal 8 doesn't have support for end times and the date module doesn't seem to be ready yet.

How would I such a date field up? I could always use a textbox, but I need to be able to set different date formats for the day of this field.

I see that there isn't a [well known option for drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173761/date-field-repeat-in-same-day-but-different-time), but hopefully there is a elegant solution for Drupal 8. Worst comes to worst, I'll accept hacky solutions....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the Datetime Range module.  It is currently an experimental module in Drupal 8, and not enabled by default.  On admin/modules it's in the **Experimental** group:

[image]

Enable it, and a new field type will appear, **Date Range**.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just got to figure out how to format the way the date fields is setup and remove the seconds part of the time.... Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisHappy Just use the custom formatter and read the docs for how to build the format string.

Comment: @ChrisHappy No, on Manage Display for the field, there should be a standard formatted named Custom Format (or similar).

Comment: This option enable start date and end date with times, whearas the questions is to have time range on same date. Formatter does have option to list only start or end date
So basically with this solution the output is  start date , time - end date, time instead of date - start time, end time

Comment: Yes as @EktaPuri says this answer doesn't provide exactly what the original post (and myself!) is looking for:

One date field, a start time, and an end time.  Is there anything that does?

Comment: [Smart Date](https://drupal.org/project/smart_date) does provide this, in a way.  See https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_date/issues/3206519#comment-14046643